# How to show < (less than symbol) using JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, jlabel

I have been programming in Java for years and I know how to do things far more complex than this, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this.  Believe it or not, I couldn't find anywhere on the web that could tell me how either.

I'm displaying a string that's stored in a variable and I need to be able to display a less than symbol/ store it in the string variable.  So far, the rest of the string prints, just omitting the less than symbol.  If it matters, I'm displaying it in a JLabel.  Also, I've tried using unicode and that didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: Why do you say "using System.out.print" in the title when you use a JLabel?

Comment: `JLabel` is unrelated to `System.in` (your original title and tag, which I replaced by "JLabel" and "swing", respectively). Also, the term "print" is normally only used for console output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JLabel` and many other Swing components [support rendering HTML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html), so if the component thinks your text is HTML, you need to escape `<` as `&lt;`.

Comment: *"Swing components assume that their text is actually HTML"*  No they don't!  The following label `new JLabel("<Hello!")` will display `<Hello!`.  It is only **once the component has determined HTML formatting should be used,** that it becomes a problem.